# Ajax Control Toolkit in .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I need some help on ajax control toolkit in asp.net Visual Studio 2010 .net frame work 
version 4.

We have hosted on interland server and it does not support ajax control toolkit .DLL as it is a third party dll.

Could anybody give us an workaround on this, can we download the source code for this toolkit which is in javascript  and can we include this .js files in our aspx pages so we can have ajax control toolkit for our website.

Any examples would be helpful if we can try this workaround working.

thanks

Comment: You mean you can't `bin`-deploy the ACT dll?

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the DLL to your `Bin` folder.

Comment: Hey my hosting provider does not leave third party dll to be hosted, as Ajax Control Toolkit is a third party open source library. DLL's are in BIN folder but does not work in my hosting server where as it's perfectly works in our local development server.

Comment: Find a better host; that's an insane policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying an ASP.net app, and your project has a reference to the relevant assembly, the dll should be copied to your .\bin folder as part of the publish process, just like the compiled assemblies that comprise your app.